# Any substructure of $(\mathbb{N}; 0, 1, +, \cdot)$ is itself

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Consider a substructure $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}; 0, 1, +, \cdot)$. Prove that $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{N}$.

EDIT: This result seems intuitively easy, but I'm having trouble finding a formal proof in first-order logic (i.e. by using the language of definable sets, Tarski's criterion, substructures, and so forth) which I'd like to see or get a hint for.

Comment: Are you talking about substructure or elementary substructure? (in this case, of course, it's the same thing, since there are no proper substructures, but the methods are different between one and the other)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm talking about substructures. If it were an elementary substructure then I could prove this statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0,1\in\mathcal{M}$; close this set under $+$.

Comment: The definition of substructures I'm given only states that any interpreted function in the substructure is merely the restriction of the corresponding interpretation in the large structure. Hence, the range is not specified (in particular, not clear to me it has to be closed under the substructure). Is this definition not correct?

Comment: @Covi: The definition of a structure, forget the sub- part, requires a function to be into the universe of the structure.

Comment: @Covi A substructure has to be a structure, so its functions have to be well-defined.

Comment: Ah I see; indeed I missed the part that substructures are themselves structures.

Comment: @Covi Of course they are!